# SQL Server database with Large Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I will have a 29 billion records on each table which is coming from other sources.

There are 12 tables in the database. Each table has 3 columns with datatypes `DateTime`, `varchar(15)`, and `float` .

I need an advice for the best solution for this case. Will SQL Server be able to accommodate all these rows?

How can I know the size of database in Gigabyte if SQL is able to accommodate all rows?

Thank you.

Comment: You can store that in SQL but your data model may better suit a non relational database like a _key value_ store. What is this data currently stored in? How often is data added, updated? How often is data read? is it at a summary or detail level?

Comment: No relationship, It just stored as is. The data is will always grow every month. If I count it, the data around  2,340,576,000 rows/month

Comment: So you just want to store the data and are not interested in ever querying it. So why even store it? I don't think you answered any of the questions in my comments.

Comment: yes, just to stored it. querying? Yes of course, but after the data is stored.

Comment: For this much data in this format (3 columns), a better storage format might be key value stores like Azure Cosmos DB, or Azure table storage or Amazon Dynamo DB. But it depends on what your final reporting looks like

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, So do you think SQL couldn't handle it? Or I've to change from SQL to Azure Cosmos DB?

Comment: SQL can handle it. But that type of data structure (three columns) might work better in a non-relational database. It looks more like key value data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of the table is Limited by available storage for your server.  Your data file can be up to 16TB.  So you can load your data to SQL Server 2014.
Please refer the document : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143432%28SQL.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Query to check Database size

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id)AS DatabaseName,
Name AS LogicalName,
size*8/1024/1024 Size_in_GB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id)='Your DB Name'
```